# SwiftCharts StackBars in TableViewCell difficult to tap

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftcharts

I have created a calendar app which uses SwiftCharts to display a time bar like this:
[image]

I nest the chart bars inside UITableViewCells. When I tap on the cells (not the event bar directly), I navigate to another view. Everything currently works great except when I tap directly on the bars themselves. It seems like there is a tapGestureRecognizer or something on the bars that is overriding the cell tap. Currently when i tap the bar the `stackFrameSelectionViewUpdater` runs, which changes the opacity of the bar, however, the print statement never runs. **Id like to either disable to tapRecognizer on the bar or have the tap trigger the segue**. Any idea how I might do either?

here is my current code:

```
barStack = ChartStackedBarsLayer(xAxis: xAxis,
                             yAxis: yAxis,
                             innerFrame: innerFrame,
                             barModels: allDayEventBar,
                             horizontal: true,
                             barWidth: 500,
                             settings: chartviewSettings,
                             stackFrameSelectionViewUpdater: ChartViewSelectorAlpha(selectedAlpha: 1, deselectedAlpha: 0.75),
                            tapHandler: {tappedBar in
                                print("user tapped bar")
                                //run segue
                            })
```

Heres the github post about the issue: [StackBars in TableViewCell difficult to tap](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/issues/292)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be caused by a layering issue unknowingly that I created by instantiating the chart in a different ViewController, then appending it to a view inside a parent ViewController. Although I never solved it a found a decent work around with a long tap gesture recognizer like this:

```
let longPressGesture:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(_:)))
longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.3 
longPressGesture.delegate = self
self.usersTableVew.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)

 func  handleLongPress(_ longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
            let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
            if let indexPath = self.usersTableVew.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
                let cellData = self.homeTableData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
                GlobalNavDelegate.homeVCDelegate!.selectedName = cellData.name
                GlobalNavDelegate.homeVCDelegate!.segueToEditPersonCal()
            }
        }
    }
```

Check out the [github post](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts/issues/292) if your curious about it